# Why exact-length list pattern matching triggers incomplete-uni-patterns in GHC?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Say I have the following file:

```hs
module Test where

a,b :: Int
[a,b] = [1,2]
```

although this looks quite irrefutable to me, while compiling with `-fwarn-incomplete-uni-patterns`:

```
$ ghc -fforce-recomp -fwarn-incomplete-uni-patterns Test.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Test             ( Test.hs, Test.o )

Test.hs:4:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-uni-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In a pattern binding:
        Patterns not matched:
            []
            [_]
            (_:_:_:_)
  |
4 | [a,b] = [1,2]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I also tried changing it to

```hs
a:b:[] = 1:2:[]
```

which still produces the same warning.

Sidenote: I know I can use tuples, just interested to know why this is considered incomplete in GHC.

Comment: The compiler reasons about the type. For a list, there are two data constructors: `[]` and `(_:_)`. It thus looks for patterns not covered by the pattern at the left side of the equation. You wrote `a:b:[]`, but only reasoning about the type `[]`, `_:[]` and `_:_:_:_` are valid patterns as well.

Comment: While GHC is justified in warning in this case, I do agree with the OP that it's rather annoying to have these warnings. Perhaps the completeness-checker can be added some extra smarts to discharge these "obvious" cases, which do come up in practice often enough. (i.e., nobody is expecting a "perfect" system, but easy things should be easy; with much less false-positive rate.)

Comment: @alias To me it looks somewhat like a warning that `1/2` might result in division by zero.

Comment: @alias I agree on `[a,b] = [1,2]` being obvious, but I don't think it's a common pattern. The completeness checker currently does a nice job, and it has been significantly improved over the years. There probably are some obvious and common patterns that should still be taken into account, but right now I can't think of any.

Comment: @chi One case I often run into is: `where [a, b] = map func [x, y]`; but I do agree that the completeness-checker did come along a long ways. There's always room for improvement though.

Comment: @alias I think the only way this could work 100% satisfyingly is if single-clause list patterns did _not_ use the list type, but a vector type `List (n :: Nat)`. Then we would need a modified version of `-XOverloadedLists` to write the expression. Could be done with an associated `type LegalLength l n :: Constraint` in [`IsList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#t:IsList), which would always be fulfilled in case of standard lists but only for `n ~ n'` in case of vectors. Then list literals of length `n` would have type `(IsList l, LegalLength l n) => l`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's no good reason.  The problem seems to be that, as per the Haskell report, the pattern binding:

```
[a,b] = [1,2]
```

is (roughly speaking) desugared into:

```
case [1,2] of ~[a,b] -> rest_of_program
```

Note the lazy pattern match `~[a,b]`.  It turns out that the coverage checker doesn't inspect values when they're matched against lazy patterns.  If you write:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall -Wincomplete-uni-patterns #-}
test1 :: Int
test1 = case [1,2] of ~[a,b] -> a+b
```

you'll get a "Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive" warning.  The coverage checker *does* inspect values for strict patterns, so if you instead write:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall -Wincomplete-uni-patterns #-}
test1 :: Int
test1 = case [1,2] of [a,b] -> a+b
```

without the `~`, there's no warning.

Of course, even if this was "fixed", it wouldn't get us very far.  The coverage checker doesn't work through arbitrary functions, so the use case mentioned by @alias in the comments would still generate a warning.  Even with a strict pattern:

```
case map f [1,2] of [x,y] -> ...
```

the coverage checker won't assume that the result of application of `map f` to `[1,2]` will be a list of length 2, so you'll still get a warning.